# How to add multiple UIViews in a UIScrollView without programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a question how to add UIScrollView in UIView.
I want to add uiview in uiscrollview using forloop without programmatically.

```
int x=0;
int y=0;
for (int i=0; i<=arr_trycelist.count; i++)
{
    [self.scroll addSubview:_subview];
    _view_design.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 320, 200);
    _scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, y);
    y=y+200;
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a special subclass of UIScrollView which does this right out of the box. It's called UITableView

Comment: i want to add subview in uiscrollview.i know your answer but some problem for add cell in tableview so

Comment: change the order of _scroll.contensize and y = y+200; because scrollview content size become zero at firsttime.

Comment: "with" or "without programmatically"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add views in scrollview using Interface Builder then you can set scrollview height like 1000 and drag n drop views with your required margin then resize frame to original and in `viewController` `viewDidLoad`

`self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width,1000);`